# Passing c-strings to class function (assigning it to class member)

Tags: c++

I have a class called Person:

```
class Person {
private:
    char name[50];
    unsigned int number;
public:
    void set_data(const char *newname, unsigned int number) {
        *name= *newname; //THE MAIN PROBLEM I WANT TO SOLVE
        this->number = number;
    }

    char* get_name() {
        return this->name;
    }

    unsigned int get_number() {
        return this->number;
    }
};
```

I have arrays:

```
const char *names[] = {"Mark", "Pavel", "Bill", "Jasur", "Jeff"};
int phones[] = { 1234567890, 9876543210, 123321456654, 1998946848479, 1234554321 };
```

I'm using `for` loop to set `Person` members:

```
Person p;
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        p.set_data(names[i], phones[i]);
        cout << p.get_name() << endl;
}
```

When I run this, I'm getting wrong output.

Comment: What wrong output? That's probably useful information.

Comment: Why aren't you using `std::string`?

Comment: Don't have fixed-length buffers in your struct. They're either way too big or way too small. Use `char*` and build in a destructor to handle releasing the memory.

Comment: To make this more C++ you should be, at the very least, using `std::string`. You should also have your "getters" in the form `const char* getName() const`. Likewise you should have individual setters, and a constructor that takes all args.

Comment: @cigien, Actually I was using `std::string`, but I was working with binary file operations, and started getting some kind of access violation errors, googled it, and saw that many people wrote about using c-string instead of `string`.

Comment: They were probably writing about it because they were making mistakes. `string` is much less error prone. If you ever need a `char` then you can convert it, but this is going to be rare.

Comment: "Some kind of access violation errors" isn't something using `std::string` will directly cause, but perhaps using something incorrectly will. That's worth fixing because using raw character buffers is going to lead to a whole world of hurt.

Comment: @tadman, @cigien; Remy Lebeau's answer helped me, I stopped getting errors working on binary files after changing the `string` type to c-string (`char` array)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `*` the way you are, you are only copying the 1st `char` into `name`. You are also not null-terminating `name` either, which is required by the overloaded `operator<<` that takes a `char*` as input.

To copy the entire string, you need to use [`std::strcpy()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcpy) (or better, [`std::strncpy()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strncpy)) instead, eg:

```cpp
#include <cstring>

void set_data(const char *newname, unsigned int newnumber) {
    //std::strcpy(name, newname);
    std::strncpy(name, newname, 49);
    name[49] = '\0';

    number = newnumber;
}
```

However, since this is C++ and not C, you really should be using [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string) instead:

```cpp
#include <string>

class Person {
private:
    std::string name;
    unsigned int number;
public:
    void set_data(const std::string &newname, unsigned int newnumber) {
        name = newname;
        number = newnumber;
    }

    std::string get_name() const {
        return name;
    }
    /* or:
    const std::string& get_name() const {
        return name;
    }
    */

    unsigned int get_number() const {
        return number;
    }
};
```